# How do we generate thumbnails for uploaded images to Box?

Tags: android, box-api

I am using the old Box API to upload files.

When my users upload images to folder in their Box account using my Android app, they complain that thumbnails images are not generated for these images on the website. If they upload images using the Box app, they are generated fine.

I should point out, that the images are not corrupted and are transferred fully. If downloaded they are identical to the file previous to upload. So the issue is, that when uploading an image using the API, no thumbnail gets generated.

How can I fix it, so it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out, which I should probably have done before asking, is that this seems to be fixed with the new Box V2 API, which the next version of my app will be using.

So using V2 API will fix this issue for me.